# how to find the abnormal id from so many ids

Tags: machine-learning, spam, spam-prevention

We run an affiliate program.  Users who sign up can gain points when they successfully recruit other users.  However, spammers are abusing this program, and automatically signing up large numbers of accounts.  We want to prevent this from happening by closing down clearly machine-generated accounts.  My idea for this is to write a program to identify machine-generated account names, or at least select a subset for manual inspection.

So far, we have found that there are two types of abnormal ids:

1. The first one is that there are some ids looks very similar to others, such as:

   - wss12345
   - wss12346
   - wss12347
   - test1
   - test2
   - ...
2. The second one is that there are some ids looks like randomly generated with out rules, such as:

   - MiDjiSxxiDekiE
   - NiMjKhJixLy
   - DAFDAB7643
   - ...

For the first one, I use the Levenshtein(edit) distance. This method can find out some ids, which was illustrate in type 1. (I have done this, and can get good performance)

For the second one, I can calculate the probabilty for the ids, just like:

```
id = "DAFDAB7643:
p(id) = p(D)*p(A|D)*p(F|A)*p(D|F)*...*p(3|4)
```

So I can use the probability to filter out the abnormal ids. (Just an idea; I haven't tried it out.)

Can anyone give me other suggestions about this topic?  How else could I approach this problem?  Can you see flaws or omissions in my attempts?

Comment: What are these IDs, where do they come from, and what is "normal"?

Comment: @Tim: I think what jordanm means is, what does a "normal" account look like? If you want to solve this using machine learning, you'll want to train a model that knows how ordinary accounts *differ* from bot-generated ones. (Also, those ids don't look like hash codes; more like randomly generated ones.)

Comment: @larsmans So far, we don't have positive(mormal) and negative(abnormal) training dataset. So I can't try out the probability method. The normal id may looks like this "happy1987,lututou01,...", which may be a word or the Phonetic representation of users' real name, but this is not a "standard" rule. So, I think may be I need more data to do this, such as the action for each registered user, and the ip address for each registered user. BUT now I can't get those data. So I hope someone may give me some suggersion about this problem.

Comment: @jordanm The normal condition is a user(a human being) to register for an account. Simply, our business model is just like that: an id can get some money if invited other people to register an account in our system. But we found that there are some ids not from human being, most likely form machines. So we need to filter out the abnormal ids.

Comment: @Tim: if this is really the only data you have, then clustering based on a string distance metric (Levenshtein, LCS, or any of the myriad options) might help. There are various clustering algorithms that work with an arbitrary distance metric, e.g. DBSCAN, k-medoids.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming that these new accounts refer back to the the recruiter's ID, I'd look at the rate and/or sheer number of new accounts associated with a given recruiter.
2. Some analysis on IP addresses or similar may also indicate if multiple users are coming from the same computer.
3. I'd use a dictionary of words, and kind of do the reverse of detecting poor passwords -- human user names should have dictionary words, personal names, lack punctuation, not include repeated characters, be mostly lower case etc.
4. Sort of going back to 1. above -- if a recruiter has an anamalously tight cluster of IDs, using the features you've already identified, would be a good flag.  I think that this might be, essentially, @larsmans comment directly under the question.

I'd be curious to know if re-purposing password checking algorithms (item 3) provides any benefit.

Comment: I Don't know what's the item 3 really means. We have a dictionary, and then there is a new id "happy4u". We will use some algorithm(such as Maximum Matching) to split the id character string as "happy/4/u". If we found more tokens in the dictionary, we would assume it as a normal id.  Did you mean about this? If not, I don't know how to do if we have a dictionary. Can you give me a more details about item 3, thanks:)

Comment: Your comment pretty much captures what I was thinking.  The feature is "if a substring of the the ID matches a dictionary word", and logic would presumably be "it's evidence that this is a non-spam ID".

Comment: Also look at information entropy metrics. There are ready-made modules for assessing password strength, which I believe work with entropy. If you don't have a body of good account names to check with, it's hard to gauge the usefulness of this approach, though.

Comment: @Dave I will try item 3 later. But I think it's hard to build the dictionary。

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling us what sort of site you are running, so this is a bit on the speculative side; but consider Stack Overflow as a prime example of successfully promoting good behavior through the use of a user reputation system, and weeding out many kinds of unwanted behaviors.

A quick, hackish fix might be to progressively deduct from the score when the amount of dormant recruit accounts grows larger, but a more rewarding and compelling fix is to award higher reputation scores for actually contributing to the site's content. However, this depends on the type of site you have; a stock market tips site, say, obviously works quite differently from a techical discussion forum.

Comment: yep, we need a user reputation system just like Stack Overflow, but we do not have it now. And every week we should pay thousands of dollars to the user who recruited more users. We need a quick solution to this problem, and we think we may have a reputation system in the next version.

Comment: Thousands!? You are begging for trouble. As a quick fix, delay the payment by e.g. a month so you have time to properly vet the winners. This may also help deter those who are only in it for quick cash awards.

Comment: delay the payment may be a good idea for a qick solution, thanks:)